# Get bootstrap typeahead parameters

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I simply want to get the "minLength" parameter of a typeahead control anywhere in my code.

How can I do this?

The controle is defined like this:

```
$('#typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 3
},
....
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var options = {
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 3
}

$('#typeahead').typeahead(options)
// and to get the minLength just use options.minLength
console.log(options.minLength);
```

Comment: But I need to get minLength in another place, where I doesn't have this "options" variable.